# Strategy for waiting for isolates in dart

Tags: dart

I have a piece of code that spawns x number of Isolates that are all running http servers. After starting the isolates my main application exits however. When testing I added the while(true) block as seen below, with an async await so the CPU doesn't run berserk. I totally forgot about it until months later when reviewing the code. It seems kind of unnecessary, although I could potentially add a kill-switch for all isolates, but it begs the question; how would I go about waiting for isolates to die off before exiting? As it is now, that while loop is keeping the entire application alive.

```dart
main() async {
  Server http_server = Server(80, 3);
  http_server.start();

  while(true) {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should create a [`ReceivePort`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.17.6/dart-isolate/ReceivePort-class.html) and then send a [`SendPort`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.17.6/dart-isolate/ReceivePort/sendPort.html) instance from this as argument to your `Isolate` instances (either create one `ReceivePort` for each `Isolate` or reuse the same depending on the amount of detail you want). By doing so, you can send data back to your main-isolate and your main-isolate will not stop because it has an open `ReceivePort` which prevents the isolate from stopping.

You can then e.g. make it so your HTTP servers can ask for the whole server to turn off. Or, you can just keep a `ReceivePort` instance open which will prevent the main isolate from stopping and without busy waiting (in that case, you don't need to send the `SendPort` instance into your isolates. Dart does not keep track of when `ReceivePort` should be closed, so you must manually close it when you think it is done).

Example:

```dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:isolate';

void main() {
  ReceivePort receivePort = ReceivePort();
  receivePort.listen((message) {
    print('Got: $message');

    if (message == 'Goodbye') {
      print('Close ReceivePort and therefore also the program since '
          'nothing else are running that could trigger an event.');
      receivePort.close();
    }
  });

  Isolate.spawn(myIsolate, receivePort.sendPort);
}

void myIsolate(SendPort msg) {
  print('Running inside isolate. Wait 5 seconds before sending message back');
  Timer(const Duration(seconds: 5), () => msg.send('Goodbye'));
}
```

Comment: That would be a nice way to add the aforementioned kill-switch and expose them through the API. I am still left with the while-loop though, albeit with some actual functionality this time. Is there really not a proper way to have main wait for Isolates to exit rather than running a loop? It feels off-putting.

Comment: @MultiTasker You don't need the while loop if you have a `ReceivePort`. You can instead have a `listen` on the `ReceivePort` which will trigger when messages are being sent to the `SendPort` you have sent into your `Isolate`.

Comment: @MultiTasker Added example of what I mean. The program does not need any loop to keep it alive. The program will automatically stop when the `ReceivePort` are closed since it was this port that kept the program alive.

Comment: You are quite right, in fact I did not even need to use the receivePort as an argument on the Isolate instantiation. The listen will keep the application alive. Thank you very kindly!

Answer (score 2):

I'd use the `onExit` handlers of the other isolates to report when they die, then listen for that in the main isolate.

So:

```dart
var exitPort = RawReceivePort();
var liveIsolates = 0;
// Don't close port while still creating new isolates.
var isInitializing = true;
exitPort.handler = (_) {
  if (--liveIsolates == 0 && !isInitializing) exitPort.close();
};

try {
  for (var i = 0; i < x; i++) {
    liveIsolates++;
    ... Isolate.spawn(...., onExit: exitPort.sendPort) ...
  }
} finally {
  isInitializing = false;
  if (liveIsolates == 0) {
    // All isolate terminated already (or `x` was zero).
    exitPort.close();
  }
}
```

This will send a (`null`) message to the `exitPort` when each spawned isolate exits. When they're all done, the main isolate closes its last receive port, and can shut down too.

Comment: @Irn `liveIsolates++` is a bad idea. The fix is before spawning set `liveIsolates`  to the number of isolates you will be spawning because in for loop `liveIsolates++` will make it 1 and then suppose the isolates exits it will decrement the `liveIsolates` inside of `exitPort` handler and the if condition will be matched `if (--liveIsolates == 0) exitPort.close();`.

Comment: That's a good point. If you are waiting for the `Isolate.spawn` future, it's possible for the isolate to exit before it's been reported as started. You have to be unlucky, but it's not guaranteed to be impossible. I'll fix the code.

Comment: @Irn replace the line  `liveIsolates++; // Ensure not closing port until all isolates spawned.` with  `liveIsolates = numberOfIsolates` and remove the if condition which is @ very bottom of main method `if (--liveIsolates == 0) {
  // All isolate terminated already (or `x` was zero).
  exitPort.close();
}` I think it should now work fine.

Comment: I could do that, but then an error being thrown during spawn would keep the port alive. But so would the current code, because I forgot to put the `--` into a `finally` block. Will fix.